# sailsjs refuses connection on address localhost

Tags: angularjs, linux, node.js, sails.js

I am developing an app consisting sailsjs in backend and ng-boilerplate in frontend. In my dev machine(64 bit ubuntu) is all working. But when I put my app for testing purposes into a 32bit debian machine, sailsjs is refusing connection on address 
    `http://localhost:1337/blog`.
When I replace `localhost` with hostname of my debian-machine, like that: 
    `http://debian:1337/blog`, all is going to work.
This is error message in browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:1337/blog net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is content my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1      debian
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters</pre>
```

This is content of my /etc/hostname:

```
debian
```

Could someone solve this mystery?
So, I add some things:
/config/env/development.js:

```
module.exports = {

  models: {
    connection: 'PeeterMongodbServer',
    migrate: 'alter'
  }
};
```

My /config/http.js is just empty, it means as it was when I have sails installed.

Comment: Provide your `http` and `env` configurations.

Comment: controller on frontend-side: $scope.getPost = function(){
                $scope.blogposts = [];
                $http.get('http://localhost:1337/blog')
                    .success(function(data){
                    $scope.blogposts = data;
              });
};

Comment: environment is set in local.js
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
  connection: 'PeeterMongodbServer',
  migrate: 'alter',
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
};

Comment: Edit your answer with `config/http.js` and `config/env`. We don't need your client code. And it's hard to read in comments, so please update answer, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try ifconfig or ipconfig as applicable
FOR e.g inet 192.168.1.64

Also update your etc/hosts file 
$ cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.64   debian

Pls ensure this is tabbed between IP address and hostname.